# cannot create instance of supersocketserver AppServer

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I am trying to get the SuperSocketServer app up an running. However, I cannot seem to create an instance of the server. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase.Config;
using SuperSocket.SocketEngine;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase.Protocol;

namespace WinnieServer
{
    class Program
    {
        AppServer W = new AppServer();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Starting...");



            while (true)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the examples in the source code. However, they all give the same error:

Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'SuperSocket.SocketBase.AppServer'

Is this the correct way to create an instance of SSS?

take care,
lee

Comment: "However, they all give the same error." - what error?

Comment: Okay, well that seems like a pretty clear error - I'd be surprised if any of the samples tried to instantiate it like that...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is exactly how they instantiated exactly the same way. When I set the references to point to the same DLL's, they too had the same error.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking at examples for a different version of the library then.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. However, I am using all of the most current examples and DLL's they have. I am hoping someone else uses SuperSocketServer and can let me know if something has changed.

Comment: Hmmm... looking at http://supersocket.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9680a878c991#SocketBase/AppServer.cs, it *isn't* abstract. Odd.

Comment: The code you've given compiles for me against version 1.5, .NET 3.5 release.

Comment: Okie. I thought I downloaded the binaries from their site. However, it turned out I had V 0.6 somehow. Thanks for your time Jon Skeet. If you post an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to delete the question, to be honest - it's unlikely that anyone else will have exactly this problem with this library and find the answer here.

Comment: Okie. I voted to close it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  The download on their home screen gives you the 1.4.4 version.  If you look in object explorer it IS abstract.  If you go to their downloads and grab the binaries zip, you'll get the 1.5 version that ISN'T abstract.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, it was the version.